# Django + SQLite how to increase SQLite timeout when "database is locked" error occurs

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am getting the: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: database table is locked` error (an oh boy are there many copies of that question) all of the answers refer to this page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errorsoption

and although I understand what is going on I clearly don't know Python and Django well enough to understand the instruction. The instruction is to increase the timeout like:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    # ...
    'timeout': 20,
    # ...
}
```

but it's not so easy for a-bear-of-very-little-brain to understand exactly where that code goes. Can someone give me a bit more context? Where in my Django project do I specify these sort of options? It can't be a general Django setting can it? Timeout sounds lika a bit too general a name for that...

Comment: all your settings lies in your project's settings.py file

Answer (score 12):

So, yes it goes in the settings file but not just directly in the settings file but under DATABASES (of course).

My DATABASES part now looks a bit like this:

```
   DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'timeout': 20,  # in seconds
            # see also
            # https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect
        }
    }

}
```

Which seems to have done the trick. Maybe this was obvious for everyone else or maybe not. It's not always so easy for a-bear-of-very-little-brain.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right to me - I expected `OPTIONS` to be inside the `default` dictionary, rather than after it.

Comment: @Alasdair is correct. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-OPTIONS

Comment: Fixed location of Options timeout in code above, as @alasdair noted.

Comment: How would a setting look like that makes use of an increased timeout during testing?

Comment: @FrederickNord I think django established all the db connection settings while starting to run the server. Also edited the answer as said by Alasdair.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea in what unit is the timeout specified? Seconds or Milliseconds?

Comment: @VishnuYS seconds, https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect

Comment: What can be a reason that I still get the error? Mouch before the program runns even 500 seconds what is my timeout limit. Let's say I get it after about 2 seconds only! Is there a maximum number of threads that can wait at the same time, a small number of about five?